# Dynamic Naming of Matlab Function

Tags: function, matlab, variables

I currently have a MATLAB function that looks like this:

```
function outfile=multi_read(modelfrom,modelto,type)

models=[modelfrom:1:modelto];
num_models=length(models);

model_path='../MODELS/GRADIENT/'

for id=1:num_models
    fn=[model_path num2str(models(id)) '/'];  %Location of file to be read
    outfile=model_read(fn,type);              %model_read is a separate function
end
end
```

The idea of this function is to execute another function `model_read` for a series of files, and output these files to the workspace (not to disk). **Note that the output from model_read is a structure!** I want the function to save the file to the workspace using sequential names, similar to typing:

```
file1=multi_read(1,1,x)
file2=multi_read(2,2,x)
file3=multi_read(3,3,x)
etc.
```

which would give `file1`, `file2` and `file3` in the workspace, but instead by recalling the command only once, something like:

```
multi_read(1,3,x)
```

which would give the same workspace output.

Essentially my questions is, how do I get a function to output variables with multiple names without having to recall the function multiple times.

Comment: I think you can use the eval function in a loop.

Comment: Why not using a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/cell.html)? It gives you exactly what you need, but wrapped in one object. You will retrieve the outputs of `multi_read` by doing `file{i}`.

Comment: Apologies to those who have replied, but I should have mentioned that the output from the model_read funtion is a structure array.  I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment I would try this approach which is more robust, at least IMHO:

```
    N = tot_num_of_your_files; %whatever it is          

    file = cellfun(@(i)multi_read(i,i,x),mat2cell(1:N,1,ones(1,N)),...
                         'UniformOutput' , false); %(x needs to be defined)
```

You will recover objects by doing `file{i}`.

Comment: +1 for avoiding `eval` and providing a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Why do you mention that this approach is more robust?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, more robust with respect to what the OP suggests. Having `N` different variables with *indexed names* doesn't look robust to me. If `N` is big you need cycles to interact with such variables and thus run-time mechanisms to obtain the variable names.

Comment: As per my amendments above, note that the output from model_read is a structure array.  I can't seem to port your answer above to work with a structure array as output.  For reference, N is ~50.

Comment: @heds1, the point still holds; [`cell`s](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) are suitable to store heterogeneous data types. In other word each cell entry can be different, e.g. `File{1}` can be a struct and `File{2}` can be a matrix and so on, thus you can have structs in them. Does this look ok to you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to do what you ask:

```
for i = 1:3
   istr=num2str(i)
   line = ['file' istr '= multi_read(' istr ', ' istr ', x)']
   eval(line)
end
```

Alternatively, here is code to do what you should want:

```
for i = 1:3
    file{i} = multi_read(i,i,x)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I am trying to avoid the use of eval.  Second answer also works, but I think the one-liner of @Acorbe is more useful.